# STM32F103 - Single-channel continuous conversion mode

Tags: microcontroller, adc, stm32, stm32f10x

I am currently trying to use continuous conversion mode on a single channel of STM32F103RB's ADC (ADC1, Channel_10 on GPIOC pin0) like described [here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/c4/63/a9/f4/ae/f2/48/5d/CD00258017.pdf/files/CD00258017.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00258017.pdf) on page 6.

Here is my configuration function for the ADC. I just took the configuration function for single conversion mode and changed it for "ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;"

```
void vHIL_ADC_Configuration(void)
{
    int n;
    ADC_InitTypeDef  ADC_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = PIN_ADC;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AIN;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    //ADC1 Config

    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_Mode = ADC_Mode_Independent;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_None;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_DataAlign = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
    ADC_InitStructure.ADC_NbrOfChannel = 1;

    ADC_Init(ADC1, &ADC_InitStructure);
    ADC_Cmd(ADC1, ENABLE);
    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1, ADC_Channel_10, 1, ADC_SampleTime_1Cycles5);

    // Calibrate ADC before start
    ADC_ResetCalibration(ADC1);
    while(ADC_GetResetCalibrationStatus(ADC1));
    ADC_StartCalibration(ADC1);
    while(ADC_GetCalibrationStatus(ADC1));

    // Buffer init

    for(n=0;n<CURRENT_BUFFER_LENGTH; n++)
    {
        f32_CurrentBuffer[n]=0.0 ;
    }
}
```

How can I get the last ADC value without using DMA ? (Since I can't just use the same function as single conversion mode like below)

```
void vHIL_ADC_readADC1(void)
{
    int i ;
    static int BufferCounter = 0 ;
    static int CurrentBufferOldVal = 0 ;
    static float f32_readCurrent = 0.0 ;

    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1, ADC_Channel_10, 1, ADC_SampleTime_28Cycles5);
    // Start the conversion
    ADC_SoftwareStartConvCmd(ADC1, ENABLE);
    // Wait for EOC
    while(ADC_GetFlagStatus(ADC1, ADC_FLAG_EOC) == RESET);
    // Get the conversion value
    f32_readCurrent=(((5.0*(float)ADC_GetConversionValue(ADC1)/4096.0)));

    if(BufferCounter < CURRENT_BUFFER_LENGTH)
    {
        f32_CurrentBuffer[BufferCounter]=f32_readCurrent ;
        BufferCounter++ ;
        f32_CurrentMean = 0.0 ;
        for(i=0;i<BufferCounter;i++)
        {
            f32_CurrentMean += f32_CurrentBuffer[i] ;
        }
        f32_CurrentMean=f32_CurrentMean/BufferCounter ;
    } 
    else    
    {
        f32_CurrentMean=(f32_CurrentMean+(f32_readCurrent-f32_CurrentBuffer[CurrentBufferOldVal])/10.0) ;
        f32_CurrentBuffer[CurrentBufferOldVal] = f32_readCurrent;
        CurrentBufferOldVal++ ; 
        if (CurrentBufferOldVal>=CURRENT_BUFFER_LENGTH)
        {
            CurrentBufferOldVal=0 ;
        }
        f32_CurrentMean=f32_CurrentMean/(float)CURRENT_BUFFER_LENGTH ;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have seen that you are using an averaging filter with a lot of burden to your MCU. A simple averaging filter is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average
You don't need to compute the sum of entire data, just first and last. At the beginning you should initialize the FIFO to the actual measured value, and then each interrupt just calculate for new measured value and discard the oldest value in FIFO.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, the first half of the averaging filter calculates the mean only on the first 10 iterations. Then we just replace the older value (pointed by CurrentBufferOldVal) by the newer value :

        f32_CurrentMean=(f32_CurrentMean+(f32_readCurrent-f32_CurrentBuffer[CurrentBufferOldVal])/10.0)

Comment: I think you should use the ADC with interrupts.